# LittleFS returning LFS_ERR_CORRUPT and LFS_ERR_NOSPC when I try to mount it

Tags: arm, filesystems, embedded

I'm porting LittleFS in a project I'm working on and when I try to mount it, it returns -84 (Corrupted). Right after that, I format the filesystem and try to re-mount it, and then it returns -28 (no space left on device).

Here's the code I'm trying to implement:

```
/* variables used by the filesystem */

const U8 lfs_read_buf[256];
const U8 lfs_prog_buf[256];
const U8 lfs_lookahead_buf[16];

lfs_t lfs;

/* configuration of the filesystem is provided by this struct */

const struct lfs_config cfg = {
  // block device operations
  .read  = FLASHEx_block_read,
  .prog  = FLASHEx_block_write,
  .erase = FLASHEx_block_erase,
  .sync  = FLASHEx_block_sync,

  // block device configuration
  .read_size       = 256,
  .prog_size       = 256,
  .block_size      = 4096,
  .block_count     = 3072, // The block count is actually 4096, but I lowered it to test. (Failed.)
  .cache_size      = 256,
  .lookahead_size  = 256,
  .block_cycles    = 200,

  .read_buffer      = (void*)lfs_read_buf,
  .prog_buffer      = (void*)lfs_prog_buf,
  .lookahead_buffer = (void*)lfs_lookahead_buf,

};

 // mount the filesystem
  int err = lfs_mount(&lfs, &cfg); // Returns LFS_ERR_CORRUPT (-84, "Corrupted")

  // reformat to try to re-mount the filesystem
  if (err) {
    err = lfs_format(&lfs, &cfg); // Returns -28 (no space left on device).
    err = lfs_mount(&lfs, &cfg);  // Returns -28 (no space left on device).
  }
```

The external Flash memory module I'm using is [Winbond W25Q128JV](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q128jv%20revf%2003272018%20plus.pdf).

I based my implementation in [this web post](https://uimeter.com/2018-04-12-Try-LittleFS-on-STM32-and-SPI-Flash/) and in [LittleFS documentation example.](https://github.com/ARMmbed/littlefs#example)

Could anyone shed some light on making it work?

Thank you.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that your `lfs_lookahead_buf` is only 16 bytes but your `lookahead_size` is 256. I don't know exactly how LittleFS uses this buffer but I suspect that it will assume that the buffer is at least `lookahead_size` long so it might be writing out of bounds?

Comment: I wish I could answer you properly, but due to the lack of documentation for LittleFS, these details are far from being clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and the issue when I screwed up my prog function. Here is my prog function as an example:

```
int lfs_w25qxx_prog(const struct lfs_config *c, lfs_block_t block, lfs_off_t off, const void *buffer, lfs_size_t size)
{
    uint32_t startAddress = block*(c->block_size) + off;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        W25qxx_WriteByte(*((uint8_t*)buffer+i), startAddress + i);
    }
    return LFS_ERR_OK;
}
```

Also, the W25Q128 can read and write 1 byte at a time, so I have those parameters set to 1 in my config, and your lookahead buffer cache size and buffer length need to match.